# KeyError in allure-pytest-bdd when executing test with --alluredir and using Examples in feature

Tags: python, gherkin, allure, pytest-bdd

I'm using pytest-6.2.4 for test automation with plugins allure-pytest-bdd-2.8.36, bdd-4.0.2. Python version is 3.6.9.

KeyError occurs when running pytest with flag --alluredir=reports.
Test contains feature with Examples:

```
| empty_answer1    | <- variable name
| ---------------- |
| {"playlists":[]} | <- variable value
| {"playlists":[]} | <- variable value
```

As far as I get, console output says that the error happens during formatting:

```
    @pytest.mark.usefixtures(*function_args)
    def scenario_wrapper(request):
>       _execute_scenario(feature, scenario, request, encoding)

/home/yuliya/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytest_bdd/scenario.py:177: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
/home/yuliya/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytest_bdd/scenario.py:143: in _execute_scenario
    _execute_step_function(request, scenario, step, step_func)
/home/yuliya/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytest_bdd/scenario.py:110: in _execute_step_function
    request.config.hook.pytest_bdd_before_step_call(**kw)
/home/yuliya/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pluggy/hooks.py:286: in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)
/home/yuliya/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py:93: in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
/home/yuliya/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py:87: in <lambda>
    firstresult=hook.spec.opts.get("firstresult") if hook.spec else False,
/home/yuliya/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/allure_pytest_bdd/pytest_bdd_listener.py:65: in pytest_bdd_before_step_call
    step_result.name = get_step_name(request.node, step)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

node = <Function test_creating_playlists__responding_to_requests[AUTOTEST-9973991-00 -  0 (9973991\u0410)-\u0421\u0430\u043b\..._number=9973991&route_dir=0&route_type=\u0410&device_type=1&trip_short_name=00&boardNumber=773410446-{"playlists":[]}]>
step = <pytest_bdd.parser.Step object at 0x7f5db6a55198>

    def get_step_name(node, step):
        name = "{step_keyword} {step_name}".format(step_keyword=step.keyword, step_name=step.name)
        if hasattr(node, 'callspec'):
            for key, value in node.callspec.params.items():
                name = name.replace("<{key}>".format(key=key), "<{{{key}}}>".format(key=key))
>               name = name.format(**node.callspec.params)
E               KeyError: '"playlists"'

/home/yuliya/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/allure_pytest_bdd/utils.py:15: KeyError
```

Examples types has been explicitly declared in a python script via example_converters, as shown further:

```
scenarios('../features/requestroutePL.feature', example_converters=dict(locality=str,
                                                                        route=str,
                                                                        trip=str,
                                                                        mmetype=str,
                                                                        statusPL=str,
                                                                        urlwithroute=str,
                                                                        urlwithroute2=str,
                                                                        empty_answer1=str,
                                                                        urlwithroute3=str,
                                                                        empty_answer2=str))
```

I've tried to escape braces with '', '%' symbols and making braces double as well. That was all in vain. Help me out please with the matter. I've run out of ideas.

The only thing that made test pass was to remove braces at all from the Examples. But this dubious step doesn't seem to be an answer. To top the whole thing off, this behavior is inconsistent, bcs the same construction in another test didn't raise any error.

Any assistance is much appreciated.